# Binding Image in ASP.NET MVC4 from a byte array

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am binding an image from a byte array in MVC4 view , The byte array is returned from  a WEB API  which I need to bind it to a view .

Below is the code

```
string str="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";

                   Byte[] image = GetBytes(str);

                    {
                        Model.ImageData = image;
                    }

 static byte[] GetBytes(string str)
        {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
            System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            return bytes;
        }
```

in view Bind it as

```
 <img src="data:image;base64,@System.Convert.ToBase64String(Model.ImageData)" />
```

The image is not rendering , it is showing an image icon only in page .

Where it is going wrong .Please suggest .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your str looks like it is already base64, so you don't need to dance to binary and back. You can just stick it in the view where it should be.

Decoding that string from base64 revealed that it is not an image, it's a pdf file.
So your api (3d party, I guess) serves you not an image.

And lastly to successfully use an image like that you probably need to specify mime type like this `<img src="data:image/png;base64,some text representation of binary data" />`

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme